# Need help with zfs import and getting plex to see datasets

Tags: permissions, mount, zfs, plex

Thanks for taking the time to read and provide any insight. So I didn't export this thing like I should have any did a force import. I have my data there in the new machine as /mnt. I can see the zpool list showing the data. I have recursively set ownership to my username with chown command. I cannot find the media data in plex to be used as a server. I am stumped as to what I should be doing from here. I am not a super user. Running on ubuntu 22.04. Thanks for any insight, I am happy to bring back more info as requested!

Comment: Please include output of: `zfs list`. It sounds like the zpool and datasets are not mounted (or at least not mounted where you expect the to be).